# Do multiple entries for the same assembly in web.config cause initial start time to increase?

Tags: .net, asp.net, performance, web-config

Can having multiply entries for the same assembly in the web.config cause an increase in the initial start time of an ASP.NET application?

For example:

`<add assembly="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources, Version=9.2.2.1380, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8FC3CC631E44AD86"/>
<add assembly="ESRI.ArcGIS.ADF.Web.DataSources, Version=9.2.2.1380, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8FC3CC631E44AD86"/>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET links these assemblies at execution time for dynamic compilation.  As such a duplicate entry (if it does not create an error) will simply be ignore as the same assembly cannot be linked twice.

I highly doubt this would introduce any noticeable overhead in your application's startup time.

**Edit:** For further reading please see [`add` Element for assemblies for compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/37e2zyhb.aspx) (as well as all the other documents that are linked to this article):

> The add element adds an assembly
>   reference to use during compilation of
>   a dynamic resource. ASP.NET
>   automatically links this assembly to
>   the resource when compiling each code
>   module.